# How to do post in FORM action when using MongDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have used MongoDB the same way it is done when it is not a react website, the problem comes when I submit the form it does not find where it is supposed to go to.

If i could be helped to understand how I will change it to work

This is how the **index.js** code looks like:

```
// dependancies
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const req = require("express/lib/request");
const res = require("express/lib/response");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("pages"));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

//conectiong using mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbBooking", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", () => console.log("Error in connecting to database"));
db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to Database Successfully"));

app.post("/book_trip", (req, res) => {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var IDcard = req.body.IDcard;
  var residence = req.body.residence;
  var phone = req.body.phone;
  var bookedDestination = req.body.bookedDestination;
  var startDate = req.body.startDate;
  var endDate = req.body.endDate;
  var adults = req.body.adults;
  var children = req.body.children;
  var messageBooking = req.body.messageBooking;

  var data = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    IDcard: IDcard,
    residence: residence,
    phone: phone,
    bookedDestination: bookedDestination,
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    adults: adults,
    children: children,
    messageBooking: messageBooking,
  };

  db.collection("bookings").insertOne(data, (err, collection) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log("Record Added Successfully");
  });
  return res.redirect("home.tsx");
});

app
  .get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.set({
      "Allow-access-Allow-origin": "*",
    });
    return res.redirect("home.tsx");
  })
  .listen(3000);

console.log("Listening on PORT 3000");
```

and this is how the react form code looks like:

```
                <form action="/book_trip" method="POST">
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      id="name"
                      placeholder="Your name"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="mail">E-mail Address</label>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      name="mail"
                      id="mail"
                      placeholder="Your email"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="IDcard">ID Image (Optional)</label>
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      name="IDcard"
                      id="IDcard"
                      placeholder="Your ID"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="residence">Residence</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="residence"
                      id="residence"
                      placeholder="Your recidence"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="phone">Phone Number</label>
                    <input
                      type="Number"
                      name="phone"
                      id="phone"
                      placeholder="Your number"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="bookedDestination">Subject</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="bookedDestination"
                      id="bookedDestination"
                      placeholder="Your destination"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="startDate">Start Date</label>
                    <input
                      type="date"
                      name="startDate"
                      id="startDate"
                      placeholder="Starting date"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="endDate">End Date</label>
                    <input
                      type="date"
                      name="endDate"
                      id="endDate"
                      placeholder="End date"
                      required
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="adults"></label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="adults"
                      id="adults"
                      placeholder="Adults"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="children">
                      Number of Children (With age)
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="children"
                      id="children"
                      placeholder="Children"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="messageBooking">Message</label>
                    <textarea
                      name="messageBooking"
                      id="messageBooking"
                      placeholder="Message"
                    ></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div id="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Can you check  network request in the browser developer tools? Where does the request go?